# Embedded Tomcat server startup failure due to SSL related issues

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, server, startup

Upgraded Spring Boot for our app from `1.5` to `2.3`, suddenly getting following error on `mvn spring-boot:run`:

```
15:48:37.617 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at com.mycompany.www.myproject.Starter.main(Starter.java:23) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1067) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1064) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:297) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1064) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
```

I don't have expertise in Tomcat and was not able to find a resolution after a long internet search duration. My SSL config looks good since it was working one week ago with Spring Boot `1.5` but fails to run for upgraded version, i.e. Spring Boot `2.3`.

`EDIT:` Here is my SSL config, assume all the variables are injected from appropriate application.yaml file:

```
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        final TomcatServletWebServerFactory httpFactory =  new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
                super.customizeConnector(connector);
                connector.setPort(port);
                connector.setSecure(true);
                connector.setScheme("https");

                final Http11NioProtocol proto = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                proto.setSSLEnabled(true);
                proto.setKeystoreFile(keyStore);
                proto.setKeystorePass(keyStorePassword);
                proto.setKeystoreType("JKS");
                proto.setKeyAlias(keyAlias);
            }
        };

       final Connector httpConnector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
       httpConnector.setPort(httpPort);
       httpFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpConnector);
       return httpFactory;
    }
```

Comment: how have you configured SSL? share the code snippet.

Comment: Hi @GoviS please check my edit, I have added the SSL config.